# How to left join below query in linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, left-join

Here I have  query to left join:

```
 lstorder = (from s in context.T_Order
                            join p in context.T_OrderDetails on s.ID equals p.Order_ID
                            join t in context.T_OrderDetailSpecification on p.ID equals t.OrderDetails_ID

                            join r in context.M_Product on p.Product_ID equals r.ID
                            join q in context.T_Preview on p.ID equals q.OrderDetails_ID
                            where s.User_ID == id && s.OrderStatus_ID == 1 && p.IsPreviewRequired == 1 && p.OrderStatus_ID == 17

                            select new orderList
                            {
                                ID = p.ID,
                                vPath = r.VirtualPath,
                                product_ID = r.ID,
                                title = r.Title,
                                amount = t.Value

                            }).ToList();
```

I need only to left join with T_Preview How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer by changing above code to :

```
lstorder = (from s in context.T_Order
                        join p in context.T_OrderDetails on s.ID equals p.Order_ID
                        join t in context.T_OrderDetailSpecification on p.ID equals t.OrderDetails_ID

                        join r in context.M_Product on p.Product_ID equals r.ID
                        join q in context.T_Preview on p.ID equals q.OrderDetails_ID into prods
                        from a in prods.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where s.User_ID == id && s.OrderStatus_ID == 1 && p.IsPreviewRequired == 1 && p.OrderStatus_ID == 17 

                        select new orderList
                        {
                            ID = p.ID,
                            vPath = r.VirtualPath,
                            product_ID = r.ID,
                            title = r.Title,
                            amount = t.Value,
                            status = (int?)a.PreviewStatus_ID

                        }).ToList();
```